# PLSQL Peformance

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have task to improve performance in some of the packages and procedures in our application.
We have around 1 package and it has subprograms around 15-20 procedures.

Below are my clarifications required.

I am making changes to datatypes from NUMBER to PLS_INTEGER for local variables and procedure parameters and in subprograms also but not all subprograms will it affect if calling package has PLS_INTEGER and subprograms has NUMBER datatype
eg.

```
PACK1.MAINPROC ( a1 PLS_INTEGER,a2 PLS_INTEGER,a3 PLS_INTEGER,a4 PLS_INEGER )

procedure SUBPROCEDURE1( a1 NUMBER,a2 NUMBER)
begin
....
end
```

As explained above main package has parameter a1 and a2 has PLS_INTEGER but in subprocedure a1 and a2 used as NUMBER will it be any issue for performance?

Comment: Benchmark it and find out.

Answer (score 0):

PLS_INTEGER probably will not improve your performance in any meaningful way.  Unless you have a tight loop with lots of mathematical operations it's unlikely you'll see any benefit from changing NUMBER to PLS_INTEGER.  And even if you do have a tight loop the best way to improve performance is usually to replace it with a set-based solution.

This question sounds like a symptom of compulsive tuning disorder.  Changing NUMBER to PLS_INTEGER is one of those changes you can always make that is simple, easy, and faster, but still ultimately worthless.

Before tuning you should have a specific performance problem and goal in mind.  Then the second task is to profile the code to find out what part is slowest and worth focusing on.  It sounds simple, but it's so tempting to focus on things that are easy instead of things that are important.

(If you've already done that, then post that information here.  If you really do have a situation where changing data types may help we'll need more details to investigate.)